# How to get access to the index in .find method

Tags: javascript, typescript

allPlans has an array of objects. The code below successfully finds the correct plan passed if _plan.name( of find method) matches this.click_Plan.
Right below it I need the value of the index of that plan and assign it here in place of index. I initially did it using for loop but I am trying to do the same with .find.

```
this.currentSection = 'Section'+index;
```

Also I need to be sure than the above statement always runs after the find is completed, do I need a call back in this case ?
And why doesn't this syntax work is that not an arrow function ?

```
 this.plan = this.allPlans.find((_plan: any) => { _plan.name === this.clicked_plan });
```

.

```
this.plan = this.allPlans.find((_plan: any) => _plan.name === this.clicked_plan);
this.currentSection = 'Section'+index;
console.log(this.plan);
```

Comment: Use `.findIndex` instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findindex

Comment: *"why doesn't this syntax work*": You need to explicitly `return` from the arrow function if you `{}` in the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.findIndex` instead, to get the *index only* initially, then select the value at the index afterwards:

```
const foundIndex = this.allPlans.findIndex((_plan: any) => _plan.name === this.clicked_plan);
this.plan = this.allPlans[foundIndex];
this.currentSection = 'Section'+foundIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). It totally works as find() but instead of returning the value it will return index of the element

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
function s(e)
{
if(e==2)
return e
}
console.log(a.findIndex(s)) //returns 1 which is index of element 2 in the array
```